# Is it an inversion in comparison?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, inversion, structure

> There is no strong theoretical or empirical motivation for the view
>   that grammatical competence is any **more** or less crucial to successful
>   communication **than** `is` *sociolinguistic competence or strategic
>   competence*.

After **than**, it seems to be an inversion, isn't it? Could you check If the ensuing parsing is right or not?

> There is no strong theoretical or empirical motivation for the view that grammatical competence is any **more** or less crucial to successful
>   communication **than** *sociolinguistic competence or strategic
>   competence* `is` crucial to successful communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second sentence isn't grammatical.

The first sentence isn't an example of inversion but of ellipsis. Certain parallel sentence structures are simply assumed to exist, even though they have been omitted.

Putting the structure back into the sentence, it would look like this (if you removed the square brackets):

> There is no strong theoretical or empirical motivation for the view that grammatical competence is any more or less crucial to successful communication than is sociolinguistic competence ***[crucial to successful communication]*** or ***[than is]*** strategic competence ***[crucial to successful communication***].

But that longer version is awkward and not something that would normally be said.

---

In other words, there is no evidence that any one of those three things (grammatical competence, sociolinguistic competence, and strategic competence) plays a greater or lesser role than any of the others.

Comment: I really thank you so much. Might I enquire of you an additional question? Could you tell me if the following sentence is ungrammatical or awkward?  "There is no strong theoretical or empirical motivation for the view that grammatical competence is any more or less crucial to successful communication than sociolinguistic competence is or strategic competence."

Comment: @jyj That's similarly awkward to your original alternative. You can save yourself some grief by dropping the *is* at the end and just saying *than either sociolinguistic or strategic competence*. (Which is also another form of ellipsis, because *competence* is assumed to apply to both *sociolinguistic* and *strategic*.)